# How to remove a button from the telebot keyboard?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I need to remove the button from ReplyKeyboardMarkup.  I search in Google very well.
The telebot library(PyTelegramBotAPI) is used.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use `telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove` to remove keyboard

```
from telebot.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove()
  
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message:True)
def all_messages(message):
    if message.text:
        
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,"Done with Keyboard",reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())

bot.infinity_pooling()
```

Comment: Вut I don't need to remove all keyboard. I need to remove only one button.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [edit_message_reply_markup](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/feffe726dd78950d5d29431c3799f4b1d9096734/telebot/apihelper.py#L1278) method to send a new set of buttons.